# Multiple SRCDIR folders for compilation using makefile

Tags: linux, shell, makefile, compilation, gnu-make

I am trying to do the following, where SRCDIRS includes all folders containing the source code by doing the following in the makefile:

```
SRCDIRS        := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type d )


$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIRS)/%.f90 Makefile
       @$(F90) $(FFLAGS) $(POPTIONS) -o $@ $<
```

My make file seems to ignore the %.o rule? 
I also have a defined $(OBJS) which includes all my %.o files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "multiply" strings that way in Make. And even if you could, you'd be specifying the wrong paths. Use [`vpath`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search):

```
vpath %.f90 $(SRCDIRS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.f90 Makefile
   @$(F90) $(FFLAGS) $(POPTIONS) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: so vpath adds all the SRCDIRS which contains the extension %.f90? 
I guess it would not matter if some files in SRCDIRS contains .f90 but are not included in the OBJS variable and dependencies, - so they will be ignored at compilation?

Comment: @A2LBK: No, you seem to laboring under several misconceptions about how Make works. And I see that you've added another question to your Question since I posted this Answer. You must retreat to simpler exercises for a while; I suggest you start with construction of a list of desired object files. *In parallel* you can try to build one object file with a specific rule. Once those work perfectly you can move on to a pattern rule.

Comment: All what was needed was the vpath, the rest issues was basically because the construction of my Makefile dependencies had some bugs. So the vpath solved essentially my problem! thanks